# Transistor Amplifier Classes

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, bjt, jfet, igbt

There are many different power amplifier classes for transistors, like: A, B, A/B, C, D, etc. But as I searched through the internet and I only found those classes referring to BJTs.

What about JFETs, MOSFETs, IGBJTs, etc., does the same thing applies for them?

[image]

Comment: It applies to valves/vacuum tubes too. (well, maybe not Class D and up...)

Comment: Historically lots of MOSFETs used in Audio Power Amplifiers. Once MOSFETS became mature technology. The MOSFET has lower risk of thermal runaway, or so we are told.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the same amplifying classes applies to FETs or other amplification devices.

What defines the amplification class is **the conduction angle and the presence (or absence) of switching during operation (like PWM modulation, etc)**, not the amplification device (transistor).

However, voltage-controlled devices like **FETs are generally better suited for switching amplification classes (D, E, F...)** due to its inherently superior switching performance compared to BJTs.

Comment: Switching performance is much "better" with FETs than BJTs. Is that because FET is voltage-controlled component?

Comment: FETs don't suffer the base charge storage effects and the like that plague BJTs, thus allowing shorter rising and falling times that reduce the switching losses. Also, hard-driven FETs can achieve very low \$V_{DS}\$ thanks to low \$R_{DS,on}\$ whereas BJTs will always have a voltage drop \$V_{CE,sat}\$ that will degrade the efficiency of switched amplification classes during the ON state.

Comment: But MOSFETs don't have that excellent performance of switching because of so many parasitic capacitances (especially the oxide capacitance), right? At least as the thing concerns of VHF applications.

Comment: See [HEMTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-electron-mobility_transistor).

Answer (score 3):

Those classes refer to how the amplifier affects the signal, not how the amplifier is constructed. Which device you choose is irrelevant.

However, I have no idea what the efficiency curve here represents.

Comment: Me neither. I just posted something so the question might be easier to understand.

Comment: Efficiency here probably refers to *collector/drain efficiency* \$\eta\$, the % of power drawn from the power supply that is effectively delivered to the load. An efficiency \$\eta\$<100% means that some power is dissipated as heat in the amplifier. There is a broader measure of efficiency, PAE (power added efficiency), that takes into account also the power delivered at the amplifier's input. For high amplifier gains, PAE\$\approx \eta\$.

Answer (score 0):

Class D to T refer to switch mode linear amplifiers using anything but a BJT.

Comment: Why not for BJTs too? They can be also used in switching applications, so why not?